# Let f (x,y) = (xy)/(x+y)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, vectors

How would I go about answering this question?

Let *f* (x,y) = (xy)/(x+y)

Find a vector **u** for which Du *f* (1,1) = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $D_uf(x,y) = \nabla f(x,y)\cdot \vec{u}$. If this is zero, what does that say about the dot product and what does that say about $\vec{u}$ in relation to the gradient?